# Counting occurrences in arrays

Tags: postgresql

Let's say there is a list of arrays

```sql
Array[1, 2, 3]
Array[4, 5, 6]
Array[1 ,2, 4]
```

And a targeted Array `a` and an integer `n`(number of matching elements)

How do we select the arrays containing the elements in the targeted array and the occurrence is greater than n?

For example,
if  `a=Array[4, 4, 4, 99]` and `n = 2`, then

```sql
Array[1, 2, 3] -- Will not match as it contains no 4.
Array[4, 5, 6] -- It will match. `a` has three `4`s which is greater than `n`.
Array[1, 2, 4] -- Will match.
```

if  `a=Array[1, 2, 4, 6]` and `n = 3`, then

```sql
Array[1, 2, 3] -- Will not match. It contains only `[1, 2]` and `n` requires 3 elements to be matched. 
Array[4, 5, 6] -- will not match. It contains only `[4, 6]` which is less than `n`.
Array[1, 2, 4] -- will match as it contains `[1, 2, 4]` as it is equal to `n`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following logic:

- Take all rows of your table, where there exists (in a subquery) a set of rows such that:

  - Using `unnest` on the column array, get the values as separate rows
  - Join this to the same thing for the input array
  - Filter the whole set so we only include it where the total count is >= 2 or whatever.

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM unnest(t.arrayCol) arr
    JOIN unnest(Array[4, 4, 4, 99]) toMatch ON toMatch = arr
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
);
```

A similar syntax

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable t
WHERE (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM unnest(t.arrayCol) arr
    JOIN unnest(Array[1, 2, 4, 6]) toMatch ON toMatch = arr
) >= 3;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/wjmWkSEf)